# Trying to make my laptop a web server

Tags: iis-7, installation

I'm trying to make my Laptop a temporary web server. It's been several years since I've set one up and I really didn't know what I was doing then =).

Long story short is that IT will not have a server ready for awhile and I need to test my site with other endpoints (PC's, iProducts, Android).

I have IIS7 installed and running. I'm using the Default Web Site that is set up and I put a simple Default.htm page in my inetpub\wwwroot folder.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div align="center">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr>
        <td align="center">My Web Site</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="center">Does It Work</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </Div>
</body>
</html>
```

Using the IP address or the computer name I can access the site locally on the laptop and see the web page.

```
http://123.45.678.90/
http://MyMachine/
```

If I go to another machine on my Intranet, I can't get to the web server. I can however Ping both the IP address and the computer name.

Is there something I have to set in IIS to make it public or something?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't access the web server from other machines on your network, but you can access it locally using a browser pointed to localhost, the problem is likely that Windows Firewall is enabled and not allowing port 80 HTTP traffic onto your machine from the network.

On Windows 7, you can access Windows Firewall in Control Panel | System and Security | Windows Firewall. Click **Advanced Settings**, and then select **Inbound Rules** from the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security window. Scroll down to "World Wide Web Services (HTTP Traffic-In)" and click "Enable Rule." This should allow inbound connections on port 80 to hit your web server.

Comment: Awesome @Myk, that was the ticket

Answer (score 1):

If it answers locally but not externally, make sure it is on a public IP and the firewall is not blocking.  This might be of use: https://serverfault.com/questions/54623/sites-in-iis-not-available-externally